# String class functions are not accessible in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, string, function, android-studio, kotlin

I've started a project in Android using Kotlin but in my classes, I'm not able to call String's functions. Here is my code:

```kotlin
val userName = et_email_signin.text.toString() 
if (userName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Name / Email could not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    return
}
```

[image: Error Img]

Comment: Try going to the Build menu and choose Clean Project. Also try File menu -> Sync Project with Gradle Files. And try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have tried it.

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happened to me after the Kotlin update, but Invalidate Caches/Restart fixed it.